# why my react native become .tsx instead .js

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

so after installing react native using `npx react-native init MyProject`  the project is running and open in emulator but the app file is not app.js instead app.tsx,

[file strcuture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG1s0.png)

The question is i am new to react native and many tutorial i see is havgin App.js file, and the code in app.js is different between js and tsx at least that's what i see, or is it just the same if i follow tutorial like folder structure, syntax and everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because of [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript)

> New projects created by the React Native CLI or popular templates like Ignite will use TypeScript by default.

Read [Using JavaScript Instead of TypeScript](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript)

You can just rename your `tsx` to `jsx`

Comment: so just rename it don't nee to do anything ? i mean tsconfig.json exist so i not really sure
is there anyway to install react native without tyepscript ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had the same concerrns earlier today while working on the current version 0.71. This version does not create a `App.js` file. What I did was- I created a file `App.jsx` and added this code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const hello = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>App</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default hello

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

it automatically renders the code in it instead of the default `App.tsx` file
You can write your JavaScript code in the `Ap.jsx` file

Answer (score 1):

While setting up your project don't use "**React native CLI quick start method**".Use **expo** instead as it is more beiggnner friendly and has App.js instead of App.tsx.To create a project using expo type

1. `npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject`
2. `cd AwesomeProject`
3. `npx expo start`

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Nowadays, typescript is the default for new projects, but **You still can create a new project with JavaScript by defining a specific version** from it's template, like this:

```
$ npx react-native@0.70 init MyNewProject --version 0.70
```

PS.: You can see the results on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZMwYLV9A-4